# iOS UITableViewController - Insert and Scroll to bottom - sometimes jumping

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, scroll, insert

I'm developing an iOS Chat App and I have a problem on the chat view. I'm using UITableViewController for the chat view. Sometimes my table jumps when new row is inserted as you can see in video: **https://youtu.be/8IgEUJ5uYAc** .

This is how I'm inserting and scrolling to the bottom of the table:

```
        self.conversation.append(message)

        self.tableView.beginUpdates()
        self.tableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: self.conversation.count - 1, section: 0)], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.none)
        self.tableView.endUpdates()


        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.tableView.scrollToRow(at: IndexPath(row: self.conversation.count - 1, section: 0), at: UITableViewScrollPosition.bottom, animated: false)
            self.footerView?.isHidden = true
            self.theMessage.text = nil
            self.switchBottomActions(showSend: false)
        }
```

Each message object has a property called estimatedMessageHeight. I'm saving there the message cell size, so tableView's heightForRowAt code is:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    guard let cellHeight = self.conversation[indexPath.row].estimatedHeight else {

        return 0

    }

    return cellHeight

}
```

Any solution?

Comment: uncheck the bounces option in storyboard ..

Comment: @Robert Constantinescu, Did you find the solution? can you please post the right answer. I too want insert and animate bottom rows like WhatsApp.

Answer (score 4):

I was also facing same issue and finally I ended up with following solution. It gives me same animation feel like we have in WhatsApp app.

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.8, initialSpringVelocity: 0, options: [], animations: {

        let reloadIndexPath = IndexPath(item: self.arrTableVwData.count - 1, section: 0)

        self.tableVw.beginUpdates()
        self.tableVw.insertRows(at:[reloadIndexPath], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.fade) 
        self.tableVw.endUpdates()
        self.tableVw.scrollToRow(at: reloadIndexPath, at: .bottom, animated: false)

    }, completion: nil)
```

NOTE: please do not pass any animation types in `options:[]` as we already passing them in `insertRows` and `scrollToRow` methods.

Answer (score 0):

Make this function:

```
func scrollToBottom(){
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        let indexPath = IndexPath(row: self.chatListDB.count-1, section: 0)
        self.tblView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .bottom, animated: false)
    }
}
```

and call it after inserting the value.

Answer (score -1):

You should *uncheck* **Bounce Vertically** in the Attribute Inspector for your UITableView.[image]

Comment: No. It did not help me.